Please assist me to resolve the problem with the installation of the Python package graphmuse
I want to explore the Python library graphmuse. It depends on PyTorch and PyTorch Geometric - see the blog here
I have created a virtual environment and used python 3.12 as the interpreter in the virtual environment.
(venv) PS 
C:\Users\phlip\OneDrive\Applic_Dev\za\co\driep01\Python_ppp\Music_Graphs\Symbolic_Music_Graph_Processing\graphmuse> python -V
    Python 3.12.

I have installed the dependencies but when I tried to install graphmuse, I get the error:
(venv) PS C:\Users\phlip\OneDrive\Applic_Dev\za\co\driep01\Python_ppp\Music_Graphs\Symbolic_Music_Graph_Processing> pip install graphmuse
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement graphmuse (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for graphmuse

I then followed an alternative procedure as suggested by the author of this blog i.e.:
From Source
You can also install GraphMuse from source. First, clone the repository:

git clone https://github.com/manoskary/graphmuse.git
cd graphmuse
Then use pip for the rest of the dependencies:

pip install --verbose git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pyg-lib.git
pip install --verbose torch_scatter
pip install --verbose torch_sparse
pip install --verbose torch_cluster
pip install partitura

However, when I run pip install --verbose git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pyg-lib.git I get another error i.e.
    File "C:\Users\phlip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3v4_nxcd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "<string>", line 42, in build_extension
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyg_lib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\Users\phlip\OneDrive\Applic_Dev\za\co\driep01\Python_ppp\Music_Graphs\Symbolic_Music_Graph_Processing\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\phlip\OneDr
ive\Applic_Dev\za\co\driep01\Python_ppp\Music_Graphs\Symbolic_Music_Graph_Processing\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\phlip\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq6n2uak_'
  cwd: C:\Users\phlip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hxja4eqz
  Building wheel for pyg_lib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyg_lib
Failed to build pyg_lib
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyg_lib)

Can anybody please give me directions on how to solve this issue?
I have executed the alternative approach and tried to run
pip install --verbose git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pyg-lib.git

again and below is the full error that I got:
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\Users\phlip\OneDrive\Applic_Dev\za\co\driep01\Python_ppp\Music_Graphs\Symbolic_Music_Graph_Processing\mg_env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize

  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)

  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__

  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"

  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'C:\\Users\\phlip\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-h03p116r\\setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\phlip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mvv7gu0w'
  cwd: C:\Users\phlip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h03p116r\\
  Building wheel for pyg_lib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyg_lib
  Running setup.py clean for pyg_lib
  Running command python setup.py clean
  running clean
  removing 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311' (and everything under it)
  removing 'build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311' (and everything under it)
  'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build\scripts-3.11' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
Failed to build pyg_lib
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyg_lib)

Thanks in advance,
Phlip

Similar issue (different OS): https://github.com/pyg-team/pyg-lib/issues/354

Have you installed the torch package first?

Hallo, yes, I have installed the dependencies PyTorch and PyTorch Geometric first

They currently only provide python 3.10 and python 3.11 version pre-build on pypi:
https://pypi.org/project/graphmuse/#files
I would recommend switching to Python 3.11 and doing the installation using pip.

hint: use virutal env with that version of Python not global installation

You should always use a virtual env with python especially for versions >= 3.12.
If it doesn't work even with a virtual env i recommend trying poetry. If it still fails to build even with poetry you should probably switch to a lesser version like 3.11

Thanks, I am using a virtual env. What is poetry and where do I get it?

https://python-poetry.org/
